# SwiftUI CoreData relationship binding Bug

Tags: swiftui, core-data

I developing simple app to calculate personal money income and consumption.

I use CORE DATA to save my model.

The models consists of this

```
CDCatalogWallet
var name: String
var ref: String

CDCatalogStateIncome
var name: String
var ref: String

CDDocumentIncome
var ref: String
var wallet: CDCatalogWallet (relationship has one)
var states_: CDDocumentIncomeState (relationship has many)

CDDocumentIncomeState
var cdCatalogStateIncome: CDCatalogStateIncome (relationship has one)
var document: CDDocumentIncome (relationship has one)
```

CDDocumentIncome  hasMany -> CDDocumentIncomeState hasOne -> CDCatalogStateIncome
The bug shows when we pushing CDDocumentIncomeState view

The model is simple.
The `CDDocumentIncome` has relationship property `cdCatalogStateIncome` (relationship many).

We open view with `CDDocumentIncome` and want to add new `cdCatalogStateIncome` to `CDDocumentIncome`

Then we open view with new `cdCatalogStateIncome`.
On this screen `cdCatalogStateIncome` has a relationship to `CDDocumentIncomeState`.

But view does not opened. Console constantly print messages

```
DocumentIncomeStateDetailView: @self changed.
DocumentIncomeStateDetailView: @self changed.
DocumentIncomeStateDetailView: @self changed.
DocumentIncomeStateDetailView: @self changed.
```

Also memory increase constantly and very fast.

[image]

I understand that the view renders constantly. But I cannot figure out what cause a bug.

The full code is available on github

[Github Project](https://github.com/sapgv/iMoney/tree/DemoBug)

Comment: You should include a reproducible example in your question not a GitHub link but you are using the word Binding, note that Binding is for value types and a CoreData object is an ObservableObject not a value type.

Comment: Ok, I understand that binding is for value type. But I have the same bug if I will use @State var id: NSManagedObjectId and pass this var as binding.

Comment: NSManagedObjectId Is a class, State is known to leak with reference types and NSManagedObjectId is not a value type.

Comment: I have tried to implement pass @State var ref: String to Binding. Result the same. Memory increase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in Old Xcode. After update Xcode to version 15.2 all issues disappeared.